# LINQ to compare item in one list to any item in another

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I wonder, if someone could help me...

Is there a LINQ query that will return a bool, if any item from one `IList<>` is contained int another `IList<>`.

These `IList<>'s` are object and I need to compare one a single property of the object, the "Name" property in this case?

Is there a LINQ query that can do this? If so could someone show me the correct implementation?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you could project both lists:

```
if (list1.Select(x => x.Name)
         .Intersect(list2.Select(x => x.Name))
         .Any())
```

Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 6):

I think this should do it:

```
bool matchExists = list1.Any(a1 => list2.Any(a2 => a1.Name == a2.Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one for your options:

```
List1.Where(l => List2.Select(s => s.Name).Contains(l.Name)).Any();
```

Comment: Updated after reading the conditions... I should learn to read before acting.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use it like below:

```
List<UserInfo> userUpd = nd.Where(x => !rd.Any(y => y.Identifier.Equals(x.Identifier))).ToList();
```